Downloading external software for a package to be pip installed
I have written a python package that requires the graphviz package to also be installed.
The pip installation of graphviz requires the Graphviz software to be separately installed beforehand.
How can I make sure that the software is installed before pip install my_package is run?
If this cannot be done then should I separately mention in say my github readme.md that the user should first install this software before running pip install my_package

There is no way. The only way is to document that the package requires graphviz. The rest is up to the users. Or create OS-specific packages that contain everything the users need.
